# How to use aggregation function mongo db-query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new in MongoDB and I would like to use the aggregation function where I want to check `type` == `topic` and get the following output

**Expected output**

```
[
    {
        conceptName : 59d98cfd1c5edc24e4024d00
        totalCount : 2
    },
    {
        conceptName : 59d98cfd1c5edc24e4024d03
        totalCount : 1
    }
]
```

**Sample input `db.GroupContents`**

```
{
    "_id" : "5a0948bb1c5edc7a5000521a",
    "type" : "topic",
    "groupID" : "5a0948bb1c5edc7a5000521a",
    "pedagogyID" : "59d98cfa1c5edc24e40249a3",
   }
```

**Sample input `db.PedagogyNodes`**

```
{
    "_id" : "59d98cfa1c5edc24e40249a3",
    "latestVersion" : "59d98cfa1c5edc24e402497f_1",
    "createdAt" : "2017-10-08 04:27:06",
    "updatedAt" : "2017-10-08 04:27:06"
}
```

**Sample input `db.PedagogyVersions`**

```
    {
    "_id" : "59d98cfa1c5edc24e402497f_1",
    "type" : "topic",
    "contentNodes" : {
        "LearningNodes" : [
            "59d98cfd1c5edc24e4024d00",
            "59d98cfd1c5edc24e4024d03",
            "59d98cfd1c5edc24e4024d00",
        ]
    },
    "createdAt" : "2017-10-08 04:27:06",
    "updatedAt" : "2017-10-08 04:27:06"
}
```

What I have tried so far

```
var groupID = "5a0948bb1c5edc7a5000521a"; // Step 1
var records;
var pnDoc;
var pvDoc;
db.GroupContents.find({groupID : groupID}).forEach(function (doc){ // Step 2
   var pedagogyID = doc.pedagogyID;
   var records = db.getSiblingDB('PedagogyService');
       records.PedagogyNodes.find({_id : pedagogyID}).forEach(function (pnDoc) { // Step 3
          var latestVersion = pnDoc.latestVersion;
          // addded aggregate function here
          records.PedagogyVersions.aggregate([
            {
                $match:{_id:latestVersion} // Step 4
            },
            {
               $unwind:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes"
            },
            {
                $group:
                {
                    _id:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes",
                    count:{$sum:1}
                }
            }
        ])
      })
});
```

I am unable to write db query based on my expected answer, please help.

> Understand my requirement

```
Step : 1 => I am passing `groupID = 5a0948bb1c5edc7a5000521a`
Step : 2 => we have to check from GroupContents where groupID = groupID then we have to take `pedagogyID`
Step : 3 => we have to check from PedagogyNodes where _id = pedagogyID then we have to take `latestVersion`
Step : 4 => we have to check from PedagogyVersions where _id = latestVersion then we have to take `contentNodes->LearningNodes`
Step : 5 => Finally we have to do the aggregation then we have display the result
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include sample documents from each of the collection in question as input since it helps with composing the right aggregate pipeline, you have already given us the expected output so that's fine.

Comment: @ chridam, please i had edited my question and i given my sample document also

Comment: Now i have to check that only `db.PedagogyVersions` collections,if you update aggregation query means , that is fine for me

Comment: Just `$unwind` the array and use `$group`. Something like this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$contentNodes.contentNodes"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$contentNodes.contentNodes",
      totalCount: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: @ Anthony Winzlet, i tried your code but nothing is printing

Comment: @chridam , i have checked it is  not working i getting like `Script executed successfully, but there is no result to show.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to unwind the `LearningNodes` array and then count them by grouping them together

```
db.PedagogyNodes.aggregate([
    {
       $unwind:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes"
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes",
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

In case you need to do any matches you can use the `$match` stage

```
db.PedagogyNodes.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{type:"topic"}
    },
    {
       $unwind:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes"
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes",
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

Answering the edited question =>

You were not able to view the output on the console since mongoshell does not print script output on the screen. To do this, do the following:

```
var result =  records.PedagogyVersions.aggregate([......]);

result.forEach(function(resultDoc){
    print(tojson(resultDoc))
})
```

Comment: I have to check one more condition also `type` == `topic`, where i have to add this condition

Comment: Kindly see my `Latest Code` section, while implementing my current code, nothing  is printing,I don't know where i have to print also ?

Comment: You have understand my question

Comment: Now check my edited code, i hope explained clearly, and i had posted sample data

Comment: For the samples you have sent, the code you have written seems right .... that being said please check that you have made no spelling mistakes for the keys

Comment: Can you please post your working code, because i had run my existing code nothing is printing

Comment: Yes i do, i have posted what something that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

To see the result of your aggregation you have to pass the callback to be executed as parameter.

```
records.PedagogyVersions.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{_id:latestVersion} // Step 4
        },
        {
           $unwind:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes"
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id:"$contentNodes.LearningNodes",
                count:{$sum:1}
            }
        }
    ], function(err, results) {
         console.log(results);
    });
```